# How to read local arrays in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have generated the following bitcode. `fuelTank` is an array that I pass to a function called `getEngineValue(int x[])`.

```
%fuelTank = alloca [5 x i32], align 4
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata !{[5 x i32]* %fuelTank}, metadata !39), !dbg !40
%0 = bitcast [5 x i32]* %fuelTank to i8*, !dbg !40
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i32(i8* %0, i8* bitcast ([5 x i32]* @_ZZ12checkFuelSysvE8fuelTank to i8*), i32 20, i32 4, i1 false), !dbg !40
call void @_Z17getFuelIndicationPi(i32* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i32]* @piston, i32 0, i32 0)), !dbg !41
%arraydecay = getelementptr inbounds [5 x i32]* %fuelTank, i32 0, i32 0, !dbg !42
call void @_Z14getEngineValuePi(i32* %arraydecay), !dbg !42
ret void, !dbg !43
```

I want to read the value stored in the `fuelTank` array. I guess I can read it from the `alloca` instruction, but couldn't find any success with it.

Note: I know how to access the array using `@llvm.memcpy`, but I don't want this.

Comment: "I want to read the value stored in the fuelTank array" - where do you want to read them? Inside the code you have provided? Inside `getEngineValue`? Somewhere else?

Comment: @Oak: inside the code I provided.

Answer (score 1):

To get a value of type `[5 x i32]` from `%fuelTank`, you can use the `load` instruction to read its content.

If you just want what is stored in a single array index (of type `i32`), you can use `getelementptr` to get the address of a specific index and then `load` it, or you can `load` first and then get the single value via an `extractvalue` instruction.

Comment: Can you tell me, how can I load the value?  Where is the load instruction?

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer if you're doing bitcode manipulation you should be working closely with [the language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

Comment: I searched a lot. I tried different ways to extract the values. I'm just stuck. That's why I'm asking. Where is this "load" instruction?

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer the language reference I've linked explains what it is. It also has the syntax for it if you're writing IR by hand; if you're using IRBuilder, you can use one of its `createLoad` methods; and otherwise you can just construct a new `LoadInst`.

Comment: I generated this code using clang. The problem here is that, clang always creates a global copy for a local array. Therefore, there is no load instruction here. Maybe, my question is still vague for you.